# Show only CN as Publisher Name for signed *.msi in Windows 10 SmartScreen Dialog

Tags: windows, code-signing, smartscreen

We are using SignTool.exe with a ComodoSSL certificate to sign our *.msi-packages on Windows. While Windows 7 only displays the company name (say "My Company Inc.") when executing an MSI which has a "mark of the web", Windows 10 SmartScreen shows "`DE, 12345, My State, My City, Our Street 123, My Company Inc., My Company Inc.`", which is not really readable.

Our certificate contains this information: 
In Windows in certificate details, the field "applicant" [note: this is my own translation from german, maybe the field name is slightly different] shows the following: CN=My Company Inc., O=My Company Inc., ...)

It worked with the same certificate on Windows 10 before setting up the new build environment. I've already tried the Windows 7 SDK and the Windows 10 SDK, same result.

Does anyone know, if I can force Win10 SmartScreen to display only the certificates Common Name?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the exact same issue with my Comodo certificate.  In my case it's an Adobe AIR app which I'm building in Flash Builder and then signing with signtool.  (Flash Builder seemingly only uses the certificate to sign the internal AIR package, not the installer EXE.)

It worked perfectly about two weeks ago, but it seems the problem began after a recent Windows update, so I assume somehow it's related to that.  I've had a support ticket in with Comodo for the past few days, but they're not responding in spite of my repeated requests via their chat support.  I think they're stumped as well.

UPDATE: It definitely seems that a Windows update is the source of the issue.  Over the weekend one of our test computers auto-updated.  Last week this computer was showing only our company name as the publisher on SmartScreen.  After the update, it shows the same long jumbled-up address string.

Four updates were installed: KB3176935, KB3176936, KB3176937, and KB3194496.  I tried uninstalling them one by one to see if it would fix the issue.  Nothing changed with *35, *37, or *96.  KB3176936 is a service stack update and cannot be uninstalled, so I have to assume it is the culprit.  However, since I can't uninstall, check, reinstall, and check again, there is no way to verify that.

Comodo Support was no help at all.  I sent them a screenshot of the issue, and their reply was: "We don't see anything wrong.  Maybe you should send us another screenshot?"  :/

At any rate, yes, I would be very interested in hearing anything you get back from Microsoft Support.  I might try putting in a ticket with them myself as well.

Comment: Okay I will contact Microsoft on monday and tell you the results as it seems to be exactly the same issue.

Comment: @okirmis did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Sadly, no :( Nobody has answered so far and I guess that won't happen anymore. Do you know if Microsoft has a public bugtracker?